# Is there a function in Google Sheets that counts the number of times a number appears in the last X entries

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Currently I have a formula that shows me the average of the last 3 entries in a sheet. The sheet is a log that has a name and then a number in each column that shows performance per day. Here is the formula

`=ArrayFormula(iferror(average(query(transpose(if(len($AB$1:$1),{COLUMN($AB$1:$1);AB15:15},)),"Select Col2 where Col2>=0 order by Col1 Desc limit 3"))))`

This has helped me but what I want to see next is how often a number appears within that range (which is 3 in this example).. For example in this range of the last 3 entries I'd like to see how often a number appears

I attempted to use a countif formula instead of average and got 0's even though there were numbers in that range that matched.

Here is my example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R4UIPJloM41nkvde5dBo6sfB-h3b-_AKhawKUiDK-DE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Use `Count()` function inside query like `Select Count(Col2)....`

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Are you able to provide an example formula to the one that i posted. I am not sure I understand

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the [**anonymous blank sheet maker**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by [*docs community forum*](https://support.google.com/) incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Comment: Here is an example of what I am looking for and the question I am trying to answer https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R4UIPJloM41nkvde5dBo6sfB-h3b-_AKhawKUiDK-DE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Showcase us the ideal expected output as well (***manually entered***) in the test sheet

Comment: I have gone ahead and updated the sheet with the ideal outcome which is now highlighted in yellow

Answer (score 0):

*[You may try](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R4UIPJloM41nkvde5dBo6sfB-h3b-_AKhawKUiDK-DE/edit#gid=1975668308):*

```js
=byrow(indirect("C2:"&rows(A:A)),lambda(Σ,if(counta(Σ)=0,,countif(choosecols(torow(Σ,1),sequence(min(5,counta(Σ)),1,-1,-1)),">2"))))
```

[image]

Comment: So I was able to use the formula on that sheet however when i transferred it to a different sheet with the same formatting it did not work.

I have added a few tabs on the workbook that shows what it looks like on my end

Same data but this sheet: refers to me copy and pasting the data into this new workbook and it working

Error in other sheet: Is an image of my other sheet and the error that I am getting by the value being zero

Comment: Recreate the non-working scenario in the test sheet & I can check it out. Can't troubleshoot just based on an image (of a different sheet you are working on) you pasted in the test sheet.

Comment: Created a new tab titled "New Data Sheet". I copied the data and created an exact match to the data i am using.

Column U is where we would be inputting the formula. However in this sheet it works perfectly. However in the other sheet that I am using thats the exact same thing I get whats on the "Error in other sheet" tab which is all zeros.